# How to check whether a div is updated?

Tags: php, jquery

I have got site with dynamic refreshing divs. 
Source:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
    $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('boo.php').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#loaddiv2').fadeOut('slow').load('boo2.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000);
    </script>
```

But I want fadeout and fadein only if boo.php return different(updated) value than actuall div. 
How compare new and actuall value and do this?
P.s Sorry for bad English but I'm Polish

Comment: do you have a specific content in the div to compare ?

Comment: I think that jQuery 1.3 is a bit old? Maybe you should update?

Comment: Shyju, I have two divs to compare: number of points and table with logs. Iro, I will update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to write an Ajax function to boo.php and compare the result with the div's value

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "boo.php",
    success: function(result) 
    {
        if($("#loaddiv").html() != result)
        {
            $("#loaddiv").fadeOut("slow")
            $("#loaddiv").html(result);
            $("#loaddiv").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to put it in the `var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        // Ajax here
    }, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a callback function that inspects the returned data and compares it to what's stored within the div already. Additionally, the functions that show/reveal the div will probably need to be moved to the callback function as well.

Documentation is available [here.](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the result you are getting from the ajax call and compare it with the current content. Assuming you have an element with ID `MsgCount` in your Ajax response and current Div Markup and you are using the value of that to compare, the below code will work

```
$(function() {
   var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){

       var currentMsgCount= $('#MsgCount').text();
       $.get("boo.php",function(data){
          var resultData=$(data);
          var newMsgCount= resultData.filter('#MsgCount').text();
          if(newMsgCount!=currentMsgCount)
          {
            //content is different. Let's show it
             $('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow',function(){
              $('#loaddiv').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
            });
          }
       });       
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I don't why it doesn't work. My code: http://pastebin.com/wf42wjia  It doesn't refresh divs :/

Comment: @AndrzejBroński : had a typo fixed now.  check updated answer and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/898eM/19/